# d3.js mouseover event not triggered when mouse is touching another element too

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js

I have a line chart with circles for each clickable point.

The problem I have is that mouseover works very well when I am over one circle and coming from blank space. But If my mouse is coming from touching the valueline, when mouse arrives to a circle mouseover is not triggered.

There are no mouseover defined for valuelines in my code, just for circles.

Probably d3 don't trigger new mouseover events if mouse is already touching another element.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like the line is overlapping the circle.

Comment: There could be all kinds of reasons, depending on how the mouse event is attached, whether or not there's a transparent fill on the line or who-knows-what. You'll need to share the code and/or a working version in order to get better help.

Comment: You're probably drawing the circles, and then the lines.  This will result in the line being on top of the circles and masking the mouseover of the circle.  Try drawing the lines, and then the circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your ideas and advice.

Finally, I solved the problem. Lines were overlapping circles.

My DOM was:

```
<g class="circles">
 ...
</g>
<g class="lines">
 ...
</g>
```

And lines were over circles.

Changing to:

```
<g class="lines">
 ...
</g>
<g class="circles">
 ...
</g>
```

Now bottom group of elements "circles" is over "lines" group.